# Django image css

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, jinja2

I can't get django to use my css file. I've done a lot of sifting through various sites and tutorials but with no luck. Most of them say to change your STATICFILES_DIRS while some don't mention it at all. I've tried changing it to about every variant that could match my style.css location as well as copying and pasting the css file into a bunch of locations which might match '/static' but nothing works!

for STATICFILES_DIRS I have tried:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/store'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/store'),
```

I also found the file manually and copied the location into a string like so:
'...Desktop/project/staticfiles/store',

I have also tried similarly playing around with the STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT to no avail.

My tree looks like this:

```
project
    static
        store
            style.css
    staticfiles
        store
            style.css
    store
        static
            store
                style.css
        staticfiles
            store
                style.css
```

and my template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    {% block head %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static "store/style.css" %}'>
    {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried changing static in the template to staticfiles

I already wasted hours on this problem and am tired and frustrated, please help!

Comment: Can you share what `STATICFILES_DIRS` end up with

Comment: in you href  tag remove "store" only load style.css beacuse you already joine the directory in you settings.py

Comment: @bdbd I have shared all the ones I used. I didn't "end up" with any because none of them worked.

Comment: @Shreyash unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: are you using this tempalate as a extended template

Comment: @Shreyash Yes, I am

Answer (score 0):

You just need one folder called 'static' and in there you can create a folder 'store' and in there you paste your 'styles.css'.

in your settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_URL = [
BASE_DIR / 'static',
]

and you reference it in your html as

{% load static  %}

href="{%  static 'store/styles.css' %} "

Comment: Exactly this ,  even in the settings.py

Comment: It worked, sorry for doubting your settings! Thank you so much for saving me such a headache!

Comment: Thats nice to hear

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mcdonald Otoyo for posting the solution!

You just need one folder called 'static' and in there you can create a folder 'store' and in there you paste your 'styles.css'.

in your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATICFILES_URL = [
BASE_DIR / 'static', ]
```

and you reference it in your html as

```
{% load static %}

href="{% static 'store/styles.css' %} "
```